# minimal dxf R13

Tags: c#, ascii, autocad, dxf

So... according to [this](http://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dxfinternals/filestructure.html#minimal-dxf-content) web page I created an empty dxf file and it worked, but as soon as I included a MText entity, autocad throws the following error

```
GroupTable dictionary was not defined in NamedObject dictionary
Invalid or incomplete DXF input -- drawing discarded.
```

So my questions are :
1- Can I trust that page and are the information on that page correct?
2- What is the last entity required in the object section?
3- What am I doing wrong?

```
  0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
  9
$ACADVER
  1
AC1024
  9
$HANDSEED
  5
FFF
  0
ENDSEC
  0
SECTION
  2
CLASSES
  0
ENDSEC
  0
SECTION
  2
TABLES
  0
TABLE
  2
VPORT
  5
1
330
0
100
AcDbSymbolTable
 70
     1
  0
VPORT
  5
2
330
8
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbViewportTableRecord
  2
*Active
 70
     0
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 11
1.0
 21
1.0
 12
0.9778937033030414
 22
-0.0911774291574901
 13
0.0
 23
0.0
 14
0.5
 24
0.5
 15
0.5
 25
0.5
 16
0.0
 26
0.0
 36
1.0
 17
0.0
 27
0.0
 37
0.0
 40
1.97341154280437
 41
2.161781285231116
 42
50.0
 43
0.0
 44
0.0
 50
0.0
 51
0.0
 71
     0
 72
  1000
 73
     1
 74
     3
 75
     0
 76
     0
 77
     0
 78
     0
281
     0
 65
     1
110
0.0
120
0.0
130
0.0
111
1.0
121
0.0
131
0.0
112
0.0
122
1.0
132
0.0
 79
     0
146
0.0
348
2F
 60
     3
 61
     5
292
     1
282
     1
141
0.0
142
0.0
 63
   250
421
  3355443
1001
ACAD_NAV_VCDISPLAY
1070
     1
  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
LTYPE
  5
3
330
0
100
AcDbSymbolTable
 70
3
  0
LTYPE
  5
4
330
5
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbLinetypeTableRecord
  2
ByBlock
 70
0
  3

 72
65
 73
0
 40
0.0
  0
LTYPE
  5
5
330
5
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbLinetypeTableRecord
  2
ByLayer
 70
0
  3

 72
65
 73
0
 40
0.0
  0
LTYPE
  5
6
330
5
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbLinetypeTableRecord
  2
Continuous
 70
0
  3
Solid line
 72
65
 73
0
 40
0.0
  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
LAYER
  5
7
330
0
100
AcDbSymbolTable
 70
     1
  0
LAYER
  5
8
330
2
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbLayerTableRecord
  2
0
 70
     0
 62
     7
  6
Continuous
370
    -3
390
F
347
21
  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
STYLE
  5
9
330
0
100
AcDbSymbolTable
 70
     2
  0
STYLE
  5
A
330
3
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbTextStyleTableRecord
  2
Standard
 70
     0
 40
0.0
 41
1.0
 50
0.0
 71
     0
 42
0.2
  3
txt
  4

  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
VIEW
  5
B
330
0
100
AcDbSymbolTable
 70
     0
  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
UCS
  5
C
330
0
100
AcDbSymbolTable
 70
     0
  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
APPID
  5
D
330
0
100
AcDbSymbolTable
 70
     5
  0
APPID
  5
E
330
9
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbRegAppTableRecord
  2
ACAD
 70
     0
  0
APPID
  5
F
330
9
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbRegAppTableRecord
  2
AcadAnnotative
 70
     0
  0
APPID
  5
10
330
9
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbRegAppTableRecord
  2
ACAD_NAV_VCDISPLAY
 70
     0
  0
APPID
  5
11
330
9
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbRegAppTableRecord
  2
ACAD_EXEMPT_FROM_CAD_STANDARDS
 70
     0
  0
APPID
  5
12
330
9
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbRegAppTableRecord
  2
ACAD_MLEADERVER
 70
     0
  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
DIMSTYLE
  5
13
330
0
100
AcDbSymbolTable
 70
     2
100
AcDbDimStyleTable
 71
     0
  0
DIMSTYLE
105
14
330
A
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbDimStyleTableRecord
  2
Standard
 70
     0
340
55
  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
BLOCK_RECORD
  5
15
330
0
100
AcDbSymbolTable
 70
     1
  0
BLOCK_RECORD
  5
16
330
1
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbBlockTableRecord
  2
*Model_Space
340
74
 70
     0
280
     1
281
     0
  0
BLOCK_RECORD
  5
17
330
1
100
AcDbSymbolTableRecord
100
AcDbBlockTableRecord
  2
*Paper_Space
340
70
 70
     0
280
     1
281
     0
  0
ENDTAB
  0
ENDSEC
0
SECTION
2
BLOCKS
  0
BLOCK
  5
1B
330
71
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbBlockBegin
  2
*Model_Space
 70
     0
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 30
0.0
  3
*Model_Space
  1

  0
ENDBLK
  5
1C
330
71
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbBlockEnd
  0
BLOCK
  5
1D
330
6D
100
AcDbEntity
 67
     1
  8
0
100
AcDbBlockBegin
  2
*Paper_Space
 70
     0
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 30
0.0
  3
*Paper_Space
  1

  0
ENDBLK
  5
1E
330
6D
100
AcDbEntity
 67
     1
  8
0
100
AcDbBlockEnd
0
ENDSEC
0
SECTION
2
ENTITIES
0
MTEXT
  5
18
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbMText
 10
2.73902
 20
2.480626
 30
0.0
 40
0.2
 41
5.0
 71
1
 72
5
 1
{\fArial|b0|i0|c178|p34;\U+FE90\U+FEB4\U+FB7C\U+FEAE\U+FE91}
 73
1
 44
1.0
0
MTEXT
  5
19
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbMText
 10
-3.37209
 20
2.054275
 30
0.0
 40
0.2
 41
5.0
 71
1
 72
5
 1
{\fArial|b0|i0|c178|p34;\U+FE90\U+FEB4\U+FB7C\U+FEAE\U+FE91}
 73
1
 44
1.0
0
MTEXT
  5
1A
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbMText
 10
0
 20
0
 30
0.0
 40
0.2
 41
5.0
 71
1
 72
5
 1
{\fArial|b0|i0|c178|p34;\U+FE90\U+FEB4\U+FB7C\U+FEAE\U+FE91}
 73
1
 44
1.0
0
ENDSEC
  0
SECTION
  2
OBJECTS
  0
DICTIONARY
  5
1F
330
0
100
AcDbDictionary
  3
ACAD_GROUP
350
20
  0
DICTIONARY
  5
20
102
{
ACAD_REACTORS
330
C
102
}
330
C
100
AcDbDictionary
  0
ENDSEC
0
EOF
```

I copied all of the numbers except for the handles from another file, should I insert all the numbers myself? if so, is there a minimum or maximum I can use?
if there is any thing else that needs explaining please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the author of ezdxf.

As the error message says, you have to add a root dict entry called ACAD_GROUP (ACAD-GROUP is wrong!), the minimal objects section should look like this:

```
0
SECTION
2
OBJECTS
0
DICTIONARY
5
C
330
0
100
AcDbDictionary
281
1
3
ACAD_GROUP
350
D
0
DICTIONARY
5
D
330
C
100
AcDbDictionary
281
1
0
ENDSEC
```

Handles are Hex-Values and they have to be unique in the current DXF file. The $HANDSEED entry in the header section should be bigger than every used handle, but i have not tested how strict AutoCAD is about the $HANDSEED value.

Uploaded a minimal DXF to bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.org/mozman/ezdxf/downloads/Minimal_DXF_AC1021.dxf

Answer (score 1):

The page you  mentioned seems a bit sparse  (but I did not look long).
Have a look at the official dxf Reference: http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/dxf/reference/

From a quick scan you are defining a dictionary with (should) contain en object with handle 39 (5-39 just under dictionary), Then you end the section without defining the object...

Comment: thank you for your time. so i defined another dictionary with the handle(5) D (the soft owner handle of the first dictionary(350)) now it just says

Comment: The following error was encountered while reading
in DICTIONARY starting at line 728:
DXF read error

Comment: I just updated the code would you mind scanning it again. Thank you